# iframe video object doesn't get loaded on Chrome, the same gets loaded in IE and FF

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, object, iframe, video

iframe video object doesn't get loaded on Chrome, the same gets loaded in IE and FF. Researched and tried a lot to fix the issue; however not to any success so far. Please find below the code that I use and help fixing the issue.

```
<div id="videoget" style="width:800px !important; height:300px !important;">
<script>
if(document.URL.indexOf("video-id") == -1){
    document.write("<img style='margin:150px 400px 150px 400px !important;' height=20  width=20 src=/ajax-loader.gif>
<iframe src='gpage/video-id/9yZnYzYTuyeruyuweyruweyuryuewy'width=0 height=0></iframe>"); 
}
</script>
</div>

<style>
object {
width: 800px !important;
height: 334px !important;
}
#videoget{
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:50px;
}
</style>








 jQuery(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var iframenew = document.frames;
        if(iframenew == null){
        jQuery(function () {
                 var timerId = setInterval(function () {
                 var iframeano = window.frames; 


                 if(iframeano!=null) { 
                       var video1 = jQuery('iframe').contents().find('object').last();;
                       jQuery('#videoget',top.document).html(video1); 
                       clearInterval(timerId);
                                     } else {}
                                                       },5000);
               });

        }
        else
        {
           var video = jQuery('iframe').contents().find('object').last();;
           jQuery('#videoget').html(video);
        }





    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

didnt check your script on waht its doing but you had some strange stuff there, mybe this will do it allready...

```
jQuery(function () { //<-- this is enough
    setTimeout(function () {
        var iframenew = document.frames;
        if(iframenew == null){
            //jQuery(function () { //<-- no need for that again...
            var timerId = setInterval(function () {
                    var iframeano = window.frames; 
                    if(iframeano!=null) { 
                          var video1 = jQuery('iframe').contents().find('object').last(); //; <-- only 1 
                          jQuery('#videoget',top.document).html(video1); 
                          clearInterval(timerId);
                    }  //else {} <-- no need for else here...
                },5000);
            //});
        }
        else
        {
           var video = jQuery('iframe').contents().find('object').last(); //;<-- only 1 
           jQuery('#videoget').html(video);
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: This works fine on IE and FF, it's just when I try doing it on Chrome, it fails. Though I made the suggested changes, but not to any success yet.

Comment: maybe you could do a fiddle, so i can testit on chrome?

Comment: The errors/warnings it shows in Chrome are similar to the ones in which I could see in IE and FF as well. I think, a work around to get the iframe rendered and then its video object loaded on Chrome, is actually needed. Thanks!!